# How to convert date to string in php?

Tags: php, yii

I have the data date from database, I want to convert become string for  input into the my function

```
<?php
    function DateToIndo($date) { // fungsi atau method untuk mengubah tanggal ke format indonesia
       // variabel BulanIndo merupakan variabel array yang menyimpan nama-nama bulan
      $BulanIndo = array("Januari", "Februari", "Maret",
             "April", "Mei", "Juni",
             "Juli", "Agustus", "September",
             "Oktober", "November", "Desember");

      $tahun = substr($date, 0, 4); // memisahkan format tahun menggunakan substring
      $bulan = substr($date, 5, 2); // memisahkan format bulan menggunakan substring
      $tgl   = substr($date, 8, 2); // memisahkan format tanggal menggunakan substring

      $result = $tgl . " " . $BulanIndo[(int)$bulan-1] . " ". $tahun;
      return($result);
    }
?>

echo DateToIndo($data->tgl_date) //is error if type date, if type string not error
```

Comment: why are you parsing your date manually? you should consider using `date() + strtotime()` functions or the `DateTime` class instead.

Comment: i agree - use the php DateTime http://php.net/DateTime class - in addition strtotime is 32bit which means you won't be able to go past year 2038 - or less than 1970.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
echo date('F d Y',strtotime($data->tgl_date));
```

Refer below URL for details

[see here for date format character](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function DateToStr(d) {
 if(gettype(d)) == 'string') return d;
 return date('Y-m-d', d);
}
```